# Duralumin submarine with heat ray

Tags: story-identification

I've been trying to find this particular book for about 10 years.

Salient points:

- Submarine with Duralumin hull.
- Young rich man invests the manufacture of said submarine.
- Has a Heat Ray for defense.
- The man's friend is a pilot and flies a collapsible plane from the submarine.
- There is a subsea treasure hunt to replenish his fortune.
- Also, a rescue of civilian prisoners from a camp.

Probably written in the 30s or 40s.

Comment: Given the time frame, this sounds like a pulp novel...and they printed lots of them!  This one is going to be tough. My first thought was a Doc Savage novel, but none of the stories match enough of your points.

Comment: I had never thought of pulp novels! I'm positive that the book was in hardcover but this is a new avenue for exploration. Thanks.